# Fill gaps between vinyl window and aluminum frame with expanding foam?

Tags: windows, vinyl, aluminum, frame, foam

I'm trying to re-trim a corner window in the kitchen. I'm not familiar with window terminology, so my apologies in advance.

It's a double paned window set into an aluminum frame. I've owned the house for about three years and the house was built in 1941. Wish I knew the history of the window (retrofit?), but alas, I don't. The previous owners / installers used Trimquick flat vinyl trim to cover the gap between the vinyl window and the wooden jambs. This leaves a void around the aluminum frame.

- Is this a normal best practice when retrofitting with a new double-paned window?
- Could I use expanding foam to fill the void between the window and jamb (that the Trimquick flat vinyl covers)? (Mostly to address potential air-draft leakage)

Thanks in advance.

[image: Image of the corner window with the aluminum frame]
[image: Additional image of the corner window with aluminum frame]
[image: Flat vinyl trim shown]

Comment: My eye caught on your "mostly to address potential leakage." You're talking about air drafts, right?

Comment: Correct, I was referring to air drafts. I'll update the post; thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I haven't a clue what "Trimquick" is, but you seem to know far more about this installation than you let on...

Comment: I could see how that gives off false knowledge of what I'm doing, lol. Peeling off the vinyl, on the adhesive strip there's "DEEPSCORE TrimQuick" labeling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expandable foam is actually code required in some locations, for window installation.

A few different manufacturers make [a foam specifically for windows and doors.](https://www.homedepot.com/p/GREAT-STUFF-12-oz-Window-and-Door-Insulating-Spray-Foam-Sealant-230612/202893747?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RKT-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_THRIFTTRAD&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RKT-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_THRIFTTRAD-71700000110012104-58700008378060424-92700076247482378&gclid=CjwKCAjwseSoBhBXEiwA9iZtxgbVOusLfqGLT-Y37FNiYucEUhKmYF1nrWuqPEhsNN0WVTLZWeJjBBoChfsQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)  It is expandable but will not cause a bow in the frame. It contracts too, so it conforms to many changing weather conditions.

Comment: Looked up code for my locale and didn't see anything regarding expanding foam (thanks for the reminder to review code). Might be why the previous installers left the void and just slapped on the vinyl trim. I'm going to fill it with that GreatStuff you posted and put on new trim. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are low-expansion-force foams intended for use around window and door frames where a traditional foam might push them out of straight. I've used them. But don't take my word for it; I'm not competent to say more than "read the installation instructions that come with the window."